# Formating phone number according to the E164 format

Tags: php, regex, validation, formatting, phone-number

I am new to php.. I want to write a script for checking the phone numbers, if they are intended to international and if they are international phone numbers I need to format them according to the E164 format. I made a regex for validating the phone number but I am stuck on formatting the phone number. Here goes the code:

```
 <?php
$replacement = '/^\s?+(93|355|213|684|376|244|809|268|54|374|297|247|61|672|43|994|242|246|973|880|375|32|501|229|809|975|284|591|387|267|55|284|673|359|226|257|855|237|1|238|1|345|238|236|235|56|86|886|57|269|242|682|506|385|53|357|420|45|246|767|809|253|593|20|503|240|291|372|251|500|298|679|358|33|596|594|241|220|995|49|233|350|30|299|473|671|502|224|245|502|509|504|852|36|354|91|62|98|964|353|972|39|225|876|81|962|7|254|855|686|82|850|965|996|371|856|961|266|231|370|218|423|353|853|389|261|265|60|960|223|356|692|596|222|230|269|52|691|373|33|976|473|212|258|95|264|674|977|31|599|869|687|64|505|227|234|683|850|1670|47|968|92|680|507|675|595|51|63|48|351|1787|974|262|40|7|250|670|378|239|966|221|381|248|232|65|421|386|677|252|27|34|94|290|869|508|249|597|268|46|41|963|689|886|7|255|66|228|690|676|1868|90|993|688|256|380|971|44|598|1|7|678|39|58|84|1340|681|685|381|967|381|243|260|263)?\s?[.]?[-]?[(]?\d{3}[)]?\s?[.]?[-]?\d{3}\s?[.]?[-]?\d+/'; $phonenumber = '+1 (123) 456-7890';

if(preg_match($replacement, $phonenumber, $matches))

{

echo "matched";

} else print_r($matches);

?>
```

Comment: Did you... did you hardcode every country code into a regex? Have you not thought about matching any digits and then checking if `$matches[1]` is a valid country code?

Comment: Yeah.. I hardcoded all the country code in the regex. I didn't know about the matching stuff so just focused on the regex and matched the whole of the phone number. When a valid phone number is provided it checks and matches it. The main problem where I am stuck is the formatting stuff with respect to the E164 standard.

Answer (score 17):

E164 is a complex undertaking because its a moving target. Having said that google is doing an admirable job with their [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber). However it's not for PHP. However Joshua Gigg was so kind to port this to PHP with his [libphonenumber-for-php](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php) and this is what I use. He is keeping it updated and in sync with the google version. There is a online demo available [https://giggsey.com/libphonenumber](https://giggsey.com/libphonenumber/)

To answer your question specifically:
Install using composer with `composer require giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php`.

Let's say you have a string representing a phone number from Switzerland. This is how you parse/normalize it into a PhoneNumber object:

```
$swissNumberStr = "044 668 18 00";
$phoneUtil = \libphonenumber\PhoneNumberUtil::getInstance();
try {
    $swissNumberProto = $phoneUtil->parse($swissNumberStr, "CH");
    var_dump($swissNumberProto);
} catch (\libphonenumber\NumberParseException $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

At this point, swissNumberProto contains:

```
class libphonenumber\PhoneNumber#9 (7) {
 private $countryCode =>
  int(41)
 private $nationalNumber =>
  double(446681800)
 private $extension =>
  NULL
 private $italianLeadingZero =>
  NULL
 private $rawInput =>
  NULL
 private $countryCodeSource =>
  NULL
 private $preferredDomesticCarrierCode =>
  NULL
}
```

Now let us validate whether the number is valid:

```
$isValid = $phoneUtil->isValidNumber($swissNumberProto);
var_dump($isValid); // true
```

This example uses a region code (CH) to format the number. This however is not necessary if the number is passed in an international format (e.g. +44 117 496 0123).

There are many, many more option to this utility and I encourage you to dive into the documentation. There is really only so much that can be done in a quick answer. I really hope that helps you and anyone else who runs across this.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is good, but this is what you would do specifically with [libphonenumber](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php) to format a phone number in E.164:

```
/**
 * Return a number formatted in E164
 * @param $num
 * @return string number in E164 format
 */
function format_E164($num) {

    $phoneUtil = \libphonenumber\PhoneNumberUtil::getInstance();
    try {
        $num = $phoneUtil->parse($num);
    } catch (\libphonenumber\NumberParseException $e) {
        var_dump($e);
    }

    return $phoneUtil->format($num, \libphonenumber\PhoneNumberFormat::E164);
}
```

Tested with a bunch of european and US numbers and it works well. You can also validate the phone number based on region etc. Here we just pass a number without a specific region and format it in E164